# Capital Gain or Loss Calculation for Mergers & Acquisitions (Canada)

Tags: taxes, stocks, canada, canada-revenue-agency, stock-split

I have a question about calculating capital gains/losses for mergers and acquisitions in which fractional shares and cash are provided as part of the transaction. What part should be listed as capital gain/loss given my adjusted cost basis (ACB) and what I received as part of the M&A? This is for US-based stocks.

In this case, CompanyA was acquired by CompanyB.
Say I had 50 shares of CompanyA at $30 per share. Ignoring the commission, the    ACB is

```
$30 USD * 50 = $1,500 USD
```

On the acquisition, I received 10 shares of CompanyB at $25 USD and $10 USD per CompanyA share. The value of this transaction is

```
$25 USD * 10 + $10 USD * 50 = $750 USD
```

Would I report a capital loss of $1,500 USD - $750 USD = $750 USD?
Or would I report the cash part of the merger ($10 USD * 50 = $500 USD) as a capital gain, then deal with capital gain/loss later when I sell the CompanyB shares? For example,

```
Capital gain now:          $500 USD
Capital gain/loss later: $1,500 USD - CompanyB settlement price on sale * 15 shares = ???
```

Any insight you can provide is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!